# React.js) React-query-devtools is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am learning reaction-query for the first time.
I installed react-query and checked that it works well. And now I'm going to use the ReactQueryDevtools tool.

However, if I install ReactQueryDevtools and add it to my code, the following error occurs.

```
<ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
```

Remove this code from App.tsx and it will run normally.

output errors (in web console)

```
QueryClientProvider.tsx:48 Uncaught Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
    at useQueryClient (QueryClientProvider.tsx:48:1)
    at ReactQueryDevtoolsPanel (devtools.tsx:438:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
useQueryClient @ QueryClientProvider.tsx:48
ReactQueryDevtoolsPanel @ devtools.tsx:438
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateForwardRef @ react-dom.development.js:19226
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21636
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
QueryClientProvider.tsx:48 Uncaught Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
    at useQueryClient (QueryClientProvider.tsx:48:1)
    at ReactQueryDevtoolsPanel (devtools.tsx:438:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
useQueryClient @ QueryClientProvider.tsx:48
ReactQueryDevtoolsPanel @ devtools.tsx:438
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateForwardRef @ react-dom.development.js:19226
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21636
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(ReactQueryDevtoolsPanel)> component:

    at ReactQueryDevtoolsPanel (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59906:5)
    at ThemeProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60636:5)
    at aside
    at ReactQueryDevtools (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59679:5)
    at App
    at QueryClientProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46246:21)
    at Fe (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:54471:60)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4026
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25892
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
QueryClientProvider.tsx:48 Uncaught Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
    at useQueryClient (QueryClientProvider.tsx:48:1)
    at ReactQueryDevtoolsPanel (devtools.tsx:438:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
```

[image]

index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { lightTheme, darkTheme } from "./theme";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";

// Create a client
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <App />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import Router from "./Router";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router />
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
"@tanstack/react-query": "^4.16.1",
"@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.16.1",
```

May I know the cause and solution of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using **react-query** **`v4`** so you have to change your import statement

**change :**

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
```

**to :**

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query'
```